# Finding all roots of complex equation with z

Tags: complex-numbers

Hi I would like to find the all the roots of the equation

$$e^{j\pi/3} z^5 + 4 e^{5j \pi /6} z^3 + z^2 + 4j =0$$

Comment: I've edited your question to include MathJax. Please ensure it's correct.

Comment: Hi yes it is correct, thanks!

Comment: My main problem lies in factorising it, I have tried converting to cartesian and substitution but havent been able to get it right.

Comment: Is it "j" or "i" ?

Comment: Its   j, where   j = Sqrt (-1), i know most people use i, but my school prefers j for some lame reason. Same thing anyways, thanks!